# In SonarQube how to authenticate users form VSTS?

Tags: authentication, sonarqube, azure-devops

Is there a way in **SonarQube** to authenticate users from **VSTS** (Visual Studio Team Services, former Visual Studio Online)?

We want users to automatically sign-in to SonarQube with the same user they use to login in VSTS. So it would save us from manually managing users.

Also, SonarQube will automatically map issues to developers who created them, send email notifications etc.

Answer (score 1):

If your VSTS users are managed by an Azure Active Directory, you can try with [Azure Active Directory (AAD) Authentication Plug-in for SonarQube](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-auth-aad). If not, there isn't any way to do this for now.